Two DocumentGroups with viewing: giving "Extra argument in call" build error
In my SwiftUI app, I have a number of DocumentGroups with a number of them set up for editing using the newDocument: variant of DocumentGroup's init that build and run fine.
I also have two DocumentGroups setup for viewing only using the viewing: variant of the init. These however fail to build when added together:
DocumentGroup(viewing: ImageDocument.self) { config in
    ImageViewer(content: config.$document, url: config.fileURL)
}
DocumentGroup(viewing: CustomPDFDocument.self) { config in
    PDFViewer(content: config.$document, url: config.fileURL)
}

When added on their own, each builds without syntax error, but when I add them together, regardless of the order, the second one raises Extra argument in call build error. Here's the screenshot,

Note that the full error in the log is of no more help:
/Users/<path redacted>/../App.swift:120:3: error: extra argument in call
                DocumentGroup(viewing: ImageDocument.self) { config in
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~

Note that the view's have been set up to record the URL using the following init,
init(content: Binding<ImageDocument>, url: URL?) {
    _document = content
    // ...
}

and return perfectly valid Views (as mentioned above, they can both build and display image and PDF documents perfectly well when added one at a time).
I guess it's down to my lack of knowledge of Swift & SwiftUI. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Ah, based on an answer in a different context, I've tried placing them in a Group and they work!
Group {
    DocumentGroup(viewing: ImageDocument.self) { config in
        ImageViewer(content: config.$document, url: config.fileURL)
    }
    DocumentGroup(viewing: CustomPDFDocument.self) { config in
        PDFViewer(content: config.$document, url: config.fileURL)
    }
}

Perhaps this is duplicate as it can be figured out from that other answer. I'd be happy to leave it here but...
